# OpenGL says "from_param received a non-contiguous array"

Tags: python, opengl, numpy, pyopengl

After installing Yosemite, I had to upgrade numpy, PyOpenGL, etc.

Now, a previously-working program is giving me the following stack trace:

```
file "latebind.pyx", line 44, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.Curry.__call__ (src/latebind.c:1201)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/VERSION/GL_1_5.py", line 89, in glBufferData
    return baseOperation( target, size, data, usage )
  File "latebind.pyx", line 32, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__ (src/latebind.c:989)
  File "wrapper.pyx", line 314, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__ (src/wrapper.c:6505)
  File "wrapper.pyx", line 311, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__ (src/wrapper.c:6439)
ctypes.ArgumentError: ("argument 3: <class 'OpenGL.error.CopyError'>: from_param received a non-contiguous array! []", (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, array([],
      dtype=[('time', '<f8'), ('data', [('cluster_index', '<i4'), ('delta_diag_out', '<f8')])]), GL_STREAM_DRAW))
```

It looks like PyOpenGL wants my array to be contiguous.   Looking at the source in numpy_formathandler.pyx in PyOpenGL:

```
if not PyArray_ISCARRAY( instance ):
            raise CopyError(
                """from_param received a non-contiguous array! %s"""%(
                    working,
                )
            )
```

And PyArray_ISCARRAY(arr) "Evaluates true if the data area of arr is C-style contiguous, and PyArray_ISBEHAVED (arr) is true."  Whereby "PyArray_ISBEHAVED(arr)
Evalutes true if the data area of arr is aligned and writeable and in machine byte-order according to its descriptor."

However, the `flags` attribute of the array that was pushed to OpenGL is:

```
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Perhaps I need to align the array?  But using `numpy.require` with `requirements={'ALIGNED': True}` doesn't seem to work.

I looked at the changes in numpy 1.9, which indicate:

> There is a new compile time environment variable
>   NPY_RELAXED_STRIDES_CHECKING. If this variable is set to 1, then numpy
>   will consider more arrays to be C- or F-contiguous – for example, it
>   becomes possible to have a column vector which is considered both C-
>   and F-contiguous simultaneously. The new definition is more accurate,
>   allows for faster code that makes fewer unnecessary copies, and
>   simplifies numpy’s code internally. However, it may also break
>   third-party libraries that make too-strong assumptions about the
>   stride values of C- and F-contiguous arrays. (It is also currently
>   known that this breaks Cython code using memoryviews, which will be
>   fixed in Cython.) THIS WILL BECOME THE DEFAULT IN A FUTURE RELEASE, SO
>   PLEASE TEST YOUR CODE NOW AGAINST NUMPY BUILT WITH:
>
> NPY_RELAXED_STRIDES_CHECKING=1 python setup.py install
>
> You can check
>   whether NPY_RELAXED_STRIDES_CHECKING is in effect by running:
>
> np.ones((10, 1), order="C").flags.f_contiguous
>
> This will be True if
>   relaxed strides checking is enabled, and False otherwise. The typical
>   problem we’ve seen so far is C code that works with C-contiguous
>   arrays, and assumes that the itemsize can be accessed by looking at
>   the last element in the PyArray_STRIDES(arr) array. When relaxed
>   strides are in effect, this is not true (and in fact, it never was
>   true in some corner cases). Instead, use PyArray_ITEMSIZE(arr).

However, `np.ones((10, 1), order="C").flags.f_contiguous` is False on my system.  So I'm stumped.  What changed that is causing opengl to think that the arrays I'm sending it are not contiguous and aligned?  Is there a way to align an array by force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to this bug in numpy 1.9 to which no one is assigned: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5224

Comment: Thanks for this, you saved me hours of frustration and an inevitable 'I give up'. "upgrading" down to 1.8.2 resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked for me too. @AdamGriffiths I think you can use the word [_downgrading_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downgrade) ;)