# Numpy bug? How do I align a numpy record array ("recarray")?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-alignment

Update: [numpy bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5224).

---

Unfortunately the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.dtype([('t', '<f8'), ('d', [('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f8')], (100,))], align=True))
b = np.require(a, requirements=['ALIGNED'])
print([x.flags['ALIGNED'] for x in [a, b]])
```

prints `[False, False]`!

How do I align `a`?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong! when you are printing "b.flags['ALIGNED']" you get False ? ('cause when I run this code I get True value).

Comment: @user3378649: I get False on numpy 1.9.  (I wrote it as a program so that there can be no doubt.)

Comment: @user3378649: Maybe try it with `'<f4'` and `'<i2'`?

Comment: Is this on 64 bits? @user3378649, is yours on 32 bits with 1.9?

Comment: @CharlesHarris: I'm running Yosemite on an i7, so I think I'm 64 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the alignment requirement in the dtype.

```
In [9]: a = np.zeros(4, dtype= np.dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i4')], align=False))

In [10]: a.data
Out[10]: <read-write buffer for 0x2f94440, size 48, offset 0 at 0x2f8caf0>

In [11]: a = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i4')], align=True))
In [12]: a.data
Out[12]: <read-write buffer for 0x2f94030, size 64, offset 0 at 0x2f8c5b0>
```

Note the difference in size. For structured types, the alignment flag was misleading in previous versions of Numpy, the requirement is now 16 bytes for strings and structured types in order to make things work correctly on SPARC. Julian Taylor gives a more extended explanation at http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/59123

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  While it works with this simple test case.  It doesn't work in general unfortunately.  Please see my updated question.

Comment: OK, looks like a bug. The `recarray` class accepts an aligned parameter, but looks to lose it in `format_parser`. Please open a Numpy issue and we can move the conversation there.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good.  Please let me know if you have seen the motivation for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484665/opengl-says-from-param-received-a-non-contiguous-array  This bug is breaking PyOpenGL I think.